# How do I customize the look of the "new article" page?

Tags: administrator, styling

Totally new to Joomla. I find the "new article" page in the administrator dashboard is very ugly, and I don't like writing prose in an ugly environment. What's the correct way to customize the look of this page? To be more specific:

1. Is there a way I can customize the HTML and CSS for *just* this page?
2. If so, how can I copy the default HTML and CSS so as to just make the modifications I want?

Comment: Might you take a screenshot of the current page, then scribble on it to show which modifications you'd like to make?  As a general rule here, those who seek coding support are expected to show evidence of research and provide any coding attempt.

Comment: @mickmackusa I don't really see how explaining what I'd like to change constitutes "research"... I don't really know what I'd like to change yet, to be honest, if I can work out how to modify the HTML and CSS I'll probably just play with it till I like it.

Comment: Okay, have you done any research at all?

Comment: @mickmackusa Looked around the Extensions > Templates menu for anything that looked relevant, but I didn't see anything relating to the New Article page. Googled a few keywords, nothing obviously relevant came up.

Comment: Truth is, I'm new to Joomla myself, so I am not going to be offering a solution.  I just like to help craft fully expressed questions here (especially when I don't have a solution).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to customize the page, you can override the "New Article" view of the Content component (com_content). 
Here is a article about overriding templates in Joomla, and it works for both backend and frontend:

[Understanding Output Overrides](https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides)

Using the override feature, you dont need to install a new template for the entire backend, you change the layout of specific pages, and your changes will not be lost, even when the component is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Its all about templates - there are some templates for the administrator interface.
Find them with google: joomla administrator templates. May be there is one that you like.

Have you tried switching the administrator template? From Isis to Hathor is quite a difference. Go to extensions, styles, select Administrator instead of Site, then set a new default.

Comment: So if I want real customization, I suppose what I should be looking up is how to create my own administrator template?

Comment: Yes - and i would start with an existing one